# Doc2Vec network architecture

Tags: neural-network, word2vec

I have been familiarizing myself with **Word2Vec** and **Doc2Vec**. After reading multiple papers including the the ones by *T Mikolov* (the creator of Doc2Vec), I am not clear on how does the neural network for Doc2Vec looks like.

I get Word2Vec: a neural network with 3 layers (1 hidden). The input layer has all words in the vocab. The hidden layer is the same size as that of embedding, while the output layer, again the same size as vocab. This is, of course, the CBOW framework.

How does Doc2Vec change things?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing just the starting randomly initialized paragraph vector is concatnated/ averaged with the randomly initialized word vector. Everything else pretty much works the same.

Comment: But then, how do we get the vectors for a doc D_i

Comment: You have a vector for doc D_i , which is concatenated with the vectors of the words, w_i in document so you get a , then you train it on the task of predicting the target word given the center word, as a result both the vectors get trained by gradient descent.

Comment: Not able to visualize it. Would a pic help? Thanks